# I want to display the larger numeric variable but it does not display anything in page

Tags: php

I want to create a function which takes two numeric varialbels as a parameter and which returns the larger of the two, without using the max function,but it doesn't display anything in page.

I am sorry that I am a beginner in php language.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>order</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         function orderFunction($num1, $num2) {
            if($num1>$num2){
               $num = $num1;    
               return $num;
            }else{
               $num = $num2;    
               return $num;
            }
            echo "the biggest is : $num";
         }
         orderFunction(10, 20);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each branch ends with `return $num;` and the `echo` is after both of these.

Comment: You could seriously though just `return max($num1, $num2);` as the while body of your function, or if you really don't like `max` (why?), then `return $num1 > $num2 ? $num1 : $num2;`. And better move the echo outside the function, per David's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderFunction` is *returning* the value before anything is ever echoed to the page, and the consuming code doesn't do anything with that returned value.  Remove the `echo` from the function and put it in the consuming code:

```
echo "the biggest is : " . orderFunction(10, 20);
```